# Are both Natsu and Igneel known as "The Salamander"?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the anime, Fairy Tail, I know Natsu is well known all around as the Fairy Tail guild's Salamander. However, I've also heard Natsu and Happy refer to Igneel as "The Salamander", specifically in the first episode. Is this a nickname for both of them?

Comment: Calling a Dragon as a Salamander? Highly unlikely. The salamander title was given to Natsu, exclusively. Also the wikia doesn't point out Igneel having that name.

Comment: In the first episode though, Natsu and Happy keep saying they're looking for a Salamander. :P

Comment: The first episode was about Natsu and Happy arriving at the town of Harujion to find someone called the Salamander (whom they **thought** to be Igneel). Natsu even states that the townsfolk must have meant Igneel and not Salamander. The mage's name was Salamander and it was not directly stated that it was Igneel's name

Answer (score 2):

Though IG_42's answer is essentially correct, it is complete.

From memory the conversation went something like this. Very simplistically. [Please edit if somebody has the subs handy :)]

> Lucy: I am a mage, looking to join a guild
>   Natsu: I am looking for Salamander, Though he turned out to be human I am looking for a dragon 
>   Lucy: (All surprised)
>   Happy: **Salamanders are fire lizard so we thought it might be Igneel**

Natsu and Happy are very simple minded. It never occured to Natsu that someone else might be using his moniker to fake people. They heard rumours of Salamander and thought it might relate to Igneel.

Answer (score 0):

Real world salamanders have been associated with fire in mythology for centuries. 
Their tendency to live in old logs sometimes used for firewood led to the belief that salamanders were immune to fire or even born from fire.

Leonardo Da Vinci notably wrote that salamanders only fed on fire.

Comment: You need to explain whether the name refers to both Igneel and Natsu. Explaining real word salamanders doesn't answer the question.